# are OneHotEncoder and keras To_categorical same?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

The length of `human_vocab` is 18377.
The length of input `X` is 1000

I'm trying to run `to_categorical`

```
np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), X)))
```

Is this the same if i apply:

```
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
onehot_encoder.fit_transform(X)
```

the output of onehot_encode is `(1000, 9739)` shouldn't it be `(1000,18377)` ?

`human_vocab` contains the corpus data that X doesnt contain
I'm trying to find the replacement of `to_categorical` due to memory issues to create hot vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
the output of onehot_encode is (1000, 9739) shouldn't it be (1000,18377) ?
```

The `OneHotEncoder` instance will create a dimension per unique word seen **in the training sample**. Here you are only showing it 9739 different words at training so it does not need more dimensions to perform one hot encoding.

One way to have it accommodate the entire vocabulary is

```py
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories=human_vocab)
onehot_encoder.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `OneHotEncoder` and `keras.utils.to_categorical` are one and the same thing where one being a class and the other being a function.